# MVC Ajax Calls Getting Very SLow performance while in Domain name but While using Localhost its working fine

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

We are trying to draw two graphs for given excel data, Graphs are working fine without any issues but the problem is when we are hosting into IIS server , We are getting very low performance if we are using machine ip address / domainsname in the same system but if we are using localhost its working fine.

For Example Published machine if I am using, 
12345.example.com/Graph - Its Very Slow ( 12345.example.com).
10.10.10.10/Graph - Its also Very Slow (using IP)
Localhost - the same above published machine while using IIS its very fast and giving awesome performance.

Is there anything do I needs to change anywhere related to host/IIS/firewall

Notes: From users machines what ever ip or domain name its loading takes huge time.

Comment: add sample you have done

Comment: Is it just the AJAX calls, or is the page load also affected?

Comment: Page is not loading everything there in session so We are drawing the Graph using session data.
While first time loading itself we are taking the excel data and keeping it in session after that if we click generate graph its taking time.,

Comment: We have changed the full functionality like Excel operations into Mongo Db then now application seems very fast and fluid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are taking more data from Excel sheets it was very slow, The application was not properly designed initially because initial idea was taking whole data into session and make use of them while generating graphs but excel sheets has more than 60-100 mb data so it made the first load very slow.

So we redesigned and changed data to fetch from mongo db now application is working fine.